# mailR task blocking R Server port

Tags: r

I've scheduled a weekly task from R Server that consists of generating a csv file and sending it via mailR package:

```
library(mailR,lib='~/packages')
sender <- "bla@gmail.com" 
recipients <- c("bla1@gmail.com","bla2@hotmail.com") 
email <- send.mail(from = sender,
                   to = recipients,
                   subject=paste0("Task, week ",min(total$week)),
                   body = "Good morning, \n\nI've attached last week file. \n\nRegards,",
                   attach.files =c(paste0("~/path/task_", substr(Sys.Date()-7,1,4)," week ",min(total$week),".csv")),
                   smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = sender,passwd = "******", ssl = TRUE),
                   authenticate = T,
                   send = TRUE)
```

It works fine, but after its first execution, when I try to connect from R Server to Google Analytics API, BigQuery... via token authentication, next message is shown:

```
Error in httpuv::startServer(use$host, use$port, list(call = listen)) : 
  Failed to create server
```

It looks like this task is blocking a port. Any idea about how to avoid this?

Thanks in advance,